# Is there a Set literal in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, set, ecmascript-6

I can [make a Set with `new Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), same way I can use the Array or Object or Boolean or Number constructors.

But **is there a set literal syntax**, like there is for arrays, objects, booleans, numbers etc?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As others have pointed out, there is no Set (or Map) literal syntax yet. There have been a few ideas floating around, in this [ES Discuss Thread](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/map-filter-map-and-more#content-20) and in the [following twitter discussion](https://twitter.com/BrendanEich/status/694007627295031297).

A few proposed syntax examples:

```
const set = {<1, "two", false>}; // by Brendan Eich
const set = {. 1, "two", false .}; // by Axel Rauschmayer
```

There are, as far as I can see, no proposals to implement any of them yet, though.

Comment: That's good mentioning twitter discussion. Helps get a better understanding. Hope the literals gets added soon. I am not using "new" keyword at all.

Comment: How about `{1, 2, 3}`. For an empty set you could do `{,}`.

Comment: @JamRisser, as it's discussed in the discussion linked above, that syntax cannot be used because, unlike programming languages like Python, JavaScript supports a shorthand syntax for objects where `{ x, y }` is `{ x: x, y: y }` assuming you already defined `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 8):

Well, there's no literal syntax for `Set()` but you can use an array instead. They are both very similar and can easily be switched between from using the functions:

```
Array.from(mySet) // Converts mySet into an array
new Set(myArray) // Creates a set from myArray
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, which already mentions using the Set constructor (which is normally given an array).

Comment: I'd say it does answer the question because the question itself is "is there a literal syntax for `Set()`" and the answer is "no, but here's an alternative".

Comment: @jered This answer is "no with no links to background discussion, but here's an alternative you that was already mentioned in the question".

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there's no single syntax for declaring a `Set`. When in doubt, [consult the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/).

Comment: While I don't think your answer is wrong, it's worth noting that that section doesn't appear to cover array literals or object literals either, so not a great source to disprove it.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Good point, I just jumped to the "literals" section. I'll fix it.